# Cordova Android release builds Ajax not working

Tags: android, cordova, lets-encrypt

Ajax calls are not working **only in release builds** but are fine in debug builds. I'm doing all calls over **https**. There are no CORS errors. Note that the issue only appears on Android, not on iOS.

I use Let's Encrypt SSL certs on the back end.

```
 SHA256withRSA
```

I have tried every fix available on SO:

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-enable-cleartext-traffic" space="^2.1.0" />
```

I verified that I have `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in manifest in the application node

I have added to config.xml

```
 <access origin="*" />    
 <allow-navigation href="*" />
 <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

and also

```
 <edit-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
 </edit-config>
```

And in `res/xml` created a file `network_security_config.xml` with content

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>
      <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
           <domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomain.com</domain>
      </domain-config>
 </network-security-config>
```

I have verified that my Let's Encrypt SSL certificate is valid, it is. I do not have whitelist plugin anymore due to Android 10+

Version are

```
Cordova Android 10.1.1
Cordova 10.0.0
```

Tested on real device running Android 6.0.1 (have to support older phones)

Nothing seems to work. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question, it might save someone A LOT of time.
The issue is that I'm using let's encrypt SSL certificates on Windows Server via Win-Acme and I had been testing on Android 6.1.0.
Following [this post](https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility.html) I just noticed that Let's Encrypt SSL certificates will not work anymore on Android < 7.1.1

Tested on Android 11 and it just worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you get any CORS erros. If you run your app on `file:` you might need `AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled` in config.xml

I suggest you to use the WebViewAssetLoader with cordova-android@10. Please check out the announcement https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/07/20/cordova-android-10.0.0.html

Comment: Like my post says, all calls are my via HTTPS and everything works perfectly in debug, including on physical device, there are no CORS error. The issue is only in release builds. All assets load fine, the issue is with AJAX. Also already had AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled.